# What scripting does Adobe Reader accept?

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader

I'm trying to control some basic settings in Edit->Preferences, like zoom level and resolution.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by setting viewer preferences. See http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=229 for some examples.

Viewer preferences can be changed using JavaScript, but the best way is NOT to use scripting, but by setting the correct entries for the `/PageLayout`, `/PageMode` and `/ViewerPreferences` keys in the root dictionary of the PDF document (aka the `/Catalog`).

Please consult ISO-32000-1 for all the possible values of these keys. The draft of ISO-32000-1 can be downloaded for free from the Adobe website.